# Sublimetext 2 and 3 (beta) rendering extremely slow with X-server for larger size screen

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I ssh to my linux server, that's 'CentOS release 6.2 (Final)'.

And use XServer to display sublimetext.

Found that both Sublimetext 2nd and 3rd (beta) render extremely slow under screen size 1024*1080, when typing or scrolling.

After I downscale display window of sublimetext. It rendering normally.

I've also ref these two pages :

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4117

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3555&start=20

Still of no use.

Comment: What happens if you run other programs at 1024x1080? Is the rendering also slow? It may simply have to do with the speed of your `ssh` connection...

Comment: Everything goes well for other problems, that's the point. I think it may due to X11/server because I use high version of centos, but I don't know how to fix it.